# Converting complex query to algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Algebra is all I know, and I cannot resolve this using my rudimentary algebra. What is the correct procedure?

> On Wednesday all items at a clothing store were $15. Brenda bought a
>   number of items.
>
> On Thursday all items after the first three were 10% off.
>
> Brenda calculated that on Thursday she could have bought an extra two
>   items with the same amount of money as she had spent on Wednesday.
>
> How many items did Brenda buy on Wednesday?

Comment: Algebra is all you know? You don't know arithmetic? On items after the first three, she saves \$1.50, so she spends \$13.50. At that rate, she has to buy 9 items to save enough to buy one more item, since $9\times1.50=13.50$. So to buy two more, she has to buy 18. That's 18 in addition to the three she has to buy for the sale to kick in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still show your efforts in writing the equations.

price = $15.

Let n = number of items she bought on wednesday.

Total money she spent = $15n$

If she bought it Thursday then :

first three items would be \$15 and rest all will be \$13.5.

Hence:

$15n = 15*(3) + (n - 3 + 2)*13.5$

Solve for n to get:

$$ 15n - 13.5n = 45 - 13.5 \\
1.5n = 31.5 \\
n = 21$$